# What is the difference between these questions "Could you tell me how renting this flat works?"or "How does it work to rent this flat"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, questions

If I want to ask someone how does it work to rent a flat which one of the sentences below Could I use?

> 1. Could you tell me how renting this flat works?
> 2. How does it work to rent this flat?

If both they are wrong, then what is the difference between 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning a question with the construction "Could you tell me if/how/when/what ..." is deemed to be more polite.

In addition, the second form is not good syntax. It would be better to say "How does renting this flat work?", but it is still a bit direct. You could end it with ", please?" to improve it.

In fact, "You could" or "Could you" is often used to make requests sound more polite (as shown in the previous sentence).

Adding "Please" at the beginning improves the request further. For example, "Please could you ...".

If you are asking several questions, you don't need to (and shouldn't) use the polite form for each question. Use it for the first question, but any follow-up questions can be direct. If you start a new subject, you might like to use the polite form again for the first question.